# SwiftUI picker driven by an enum: value not updated

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-picker

According to Apple's documentation regarding [Picker in SwiftUI using an Enum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker), if the enum conforms to the `Identifiable` protocol in addition to `CaseIterable`, a picker iterating over all cases should update the bound variable natively.

I tested it, and it does not work as expected.

```
enum Flavor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case chocolate
    case vanilla
    case strawberry

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

struct EnumView: View {
    @State private var selectedFlavor = Flavor.chocolate
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Flavor", selection: $selectedFlavor) {
                ForEach(Flavor.allCases) { flavor in
                    Text(flavor.rawValue.capitalized)//.tag(flavor)
                }
            }
        
            Text("Selected flavor: \(selectedFlavor.rawValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

However, if I pass a `tag` for each view, it works.

[image]

What's happening here? Is the Apple documentation wrong? The `selectedFlavor` variable expects a value of type `Flavor`, but the id used in the picker is actually a `String`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a `Picker` to work properly, its elements need to be identified.

Note that the `selectedFlavor` variable is of type `Flavor`. Which means the options in the Picker should be identified as Flavors (not Strings).

However, in your code your `id` is of type `String`:

```
var id: String { self.rawValue }
```

---

You can either:

- provide a `tag` (of type `Flavor`):

```
Text(flavor.rawValue.capitalized)
    .tag(flavor)
```

- conform `Flavor` to `Identifiable` by providing a custom `id` of type `Flavor`:

```
var id: Flavor { self }
```

- specify the `id` parameter (of type `Flavor`) explicitly in the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(Flavor.allCases, id: \.self) { ... }
```

- change the `selectedFlavor` to be a String:

```
@State private var selectedFlavor = Flavor.chocolate.rawValue
```

Comment: But when the elements conform to Identifiable, the ForEach should automatically assigns a tag to the selection views in the picker, using each option’s id. I don't understand why the picker does not automatically convert the string id used as the tag to the enum with the rawValue of this id used as a tag.

Comment: @alpennec I added a more detailed explanation. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It's good to have all the possible options listed.

If I understand well, when the items passed to the ForEach loop conform to Identifiable (i.e. we don't need to tell the id to use), the generated tags for each view in the ForEach loop is the id? So if we have an id of type String for an Enum, then the tag for the view is a String, and when the picker selects an item, it selects a String whereas the expected value for the selection is an Enum. Is that correct?

Comment: @alpennec Yes, that's right. Basically the issue was about tagging values with Strings and expecting a Flavor as the selected item.

Answer (score 4):

This is an addition to @pawello2222 already awesome answer.

Just to clarify that the solution to conform the enum to Identifiable using the below code works to correctly tag the UI picker without explicitly declaring it within the picker code:

```
var id: Flavor { self }
```

The official [Apple documentation for the swiftUI picker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker) says to id the enum using `var id: String { self.rawValue }` and does not work as expected using the rest of the example code.